# how to properly use axios.delete in a separate service module for the backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My code uses axios.delete. It deletes the object after you reload the page. I want the page updates render automatically after deleting the object.

Here's my code in App.js file.
(uses a button to delete)

```
    const onClickDelete = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()
        const result = window.confirm('delete?')
        const id = event.target.value
        console.log(persons)
        if(result){
            contactService
                .removeContact(id)
                    .then(returnedContacts => {
                        setPersons(returnedContacts.filter(contact =>
                            {return contact.id !== id}
                        ))
                    })
                    .catch(error =>{
                        console.log(error)
                    })
        }
    }
```

I have another file imported to App.js.
Here's the code.(for delete)

```
const removeContact = id =>{
    const request = axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}
```